# Aligning and adding columns in multiple Pandas dataframes based on Date column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of dataframes all which contain columns labeled 'Date' and 'Cost' along with additional columns.  I'd like to add the numerical data in the 'Cost' columns across the different frames based on lining up the dates in the 'Date' columns to provide a timeseries of total costs for each of the dates.

There are different numbers of rows in each of the dataframes.

This seems like something that Pandas should be well suited to doing, but I can't find a clean solution.

Any help appreciated!

Here are two of the dataframes:

```
df1:
Date  Total Cost  Funded Costs  
0 2015-09-30      724824        940451   
1 2015-10-31      757605        940451     
2 2015-11-15      788051        940451     
3 2015-11-30      809368        940451    

df2:
Date  Total Cost  Funded Costs  
0 2015-11-30        3022         60000    
1 2016-01-15        3051         60000
```

I want to have the resulting dataframe have five rows (there are five different dates) and a single column with the total of the 'Total Cost' column from each of the dataframes.  Initially I used the following:

```
totalFunding = df1['Total Cost'].values + df2['Total Cost'].values
```

This worked fine until there were different dates in each of the dataframes.

Thanks!

The solution posted below works great, except that I need to do this recursively as I have a number of data frames.  I created the following function:

```
def addDataFrames(f_arg, *argv):
    dfTotal = f_arg
    for arg in argv:
        dfTotal = dfTotal.set_index('Date').add(arg.set_index('Date'), fill_value = 0)
return dfTotal
```

Which works fine when adding the first two dataframes.  However, the addition method appears to convert my Date column into an index in the resulting sum and therefore subsequent passes through the function fail.  Here is what dfTotal looks like after the first two data frames are added together:

```
            Total Cost  Funded Costs  Remaining Cost  Total Employee Hours
Date                                                                      
2015-09-30     1449648       1880902          431254                7410.6
2015-10-31     1515210       1880902          365692                7874.4
2015-11-15     1576102       1880902          304800                8367.2
2015-11-30     1618736       1880902          262166                8578.0
2015-12-15     1671462       1880902          209440                8945.2
2015-12-31     1721840       1880902          159062                9161.2
2016-01-15     1764894       1880902          116008                9495.0
```

Note that what was originally a column in the dataframe called 'Date' is now listed as the index causing df.set_index('Date') to generate an error on subsequent passes through my function.

Comment: post representative data, your code to create the dfs, your attempts, and the desired output

Answer (score 1):

DataFrame.add does exactly what you're looking for; it matches the DataFrames based on index, so:

```
df1.set_index('Date').add(df2.set_index('Date'), fill_value=0)
```

should do the trick. If you just want the Total Cost column and you want it as a DataFrame:

```
df1.set_index('Date').add(df2.set_index('Date'), fill_value=0)[['Total Cost']]
```

See also the documentation for DataFrame.add at:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.  As mentioned, the add method converted the 'Date' column into the dataframe index.  This was resolved using:

```
dfTotal['Date'] = dfTotal.index
```

The complete function is then:

```
def addDataFrames(f_arg, *argv):
dfTotal = f_arg
for arg in argv:
    dfTotal = dfTotal.set_index('Date').add(arg.set_index('Date'), fill_value = 0)
    dfTotal['Date'] = dfTotal.index
return dfTotal
```